# Did I branch or not? How to merge 2 branches

Tags: branch

I'm HMS confused

I today created a branch to work on implementation of a new feature. I thought this branching was successful as these appeared. [image: branches]

However I'd like to merge the new feature branch (NGUI interface test) back into the default main branch **but I don't have the option to if I right click on the most recent commit.**

Plus, I've seen on other posts that the graph should be showing a branch of different colours from where the branching occurred, like in this eg.

[image: eg]

All advice appreciated, just discovered DVCS and think it is so elegant.
T

Comment: my apologies, I thought I clicked through from Atlassian support! Will repost at stack overflow. Thanks

Comment: For future reference, a [guide to where git questions go](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6311/40980).  There *are* git questions appropriate to P.SE that deal more with the workflow, when to branch, and such.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you probably need to switch to the "default" branch before you can merge in your new NGUI branch. Otherwise, there's not much point in merging a branch into itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is anything wrong with your branch. You don't really see two parallel tracks of development since nothing has happened to the `default` branch since you created the feature branch.

When merging, you are merging something *into* the branch you are currently working on, and you want to merge the `NGUI ..` branch into the `default` branch.

So what you need to do is to switch back to the `default` branch, and merge in your feature branch.

If working with git (I don't if this also applies to Mercurial), this particular case would result in a 'fast forward' merge - where the history does not really reflect that a feature branch has been merged into the main branch (two parallel tracks in the history). This is because there is no work done in the main branch, and your feature branch is directly ahead of the main branch.

So in git, to force the history to reflect this, you need to use a *no fast forward* option when merging.